# Trying to create a data frame with all possible combinations of N categorical variables

Tags: r

I'm running a regression on about 5 different categorical variables with 5 layers. I want to build a data frame where each row is a different combination of those variables. I know this is possible in R but I'm running into issues finding the syntax.

I know u can do:

```
unique(df[c('x','y','z')])
```

to find the unique values combinations across the columns but I don't think you can use that syntax as I want.

ideally I'd like the DF to look like:

row 1: x1, y1, z1

row 2: x1, y1, z2

etc

Also I tried replicating :

```
> x1<-rep(c(1,2,3,4,5),times=4)
> x2<-rep(c("A","B","C","D"),each=5)
> x3<-letters[1:20]
> x4<-rep(c(5,10,15,20),times=c(2,8,6,4))
> df<-data.frame(x1,x2,x3,x4)

unique(df[c("x2","x4")])
```

But the number of unique levels of my variables is different, so I get the error:

```
Error in data.frame(x1, x2, x3, x4) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 26, 12, 215, 6
```

So not sure how to work around this.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you may try `expand.grid` like below (assuming `df` is defined as below)

```
df <- data.frame(x = paste0("x",1:5),y = paste0("y",1:5),z = paste0("z",1:5))
```

then

```
> expand.grid(df)
     x  y  z
1   x1 y1 z1
2   x2 y1 z1
3   x3 y1 z1
4   x4 y1 z1
5   x5 y1 z1
6   x1 y2 z1
7   x2 y2 z1
8   x3 y2 z1
9   x4 y2 z1
10  x5 y2 z1
11  x1 y3 z1
12  x2 y3 z1
13  x3 y3 z1
14  x4 y3 z1
15  x5 y3 z1
16  x1 y4 z1
17  x2 y4 z1
18  x3 y4 z1
19  x4 y4 z1
20  x5 y4 z1
21  x1 y5 z1
22  x2 y5 z1
23  x3 y5 z1
24  x4 y5 z1
25  x5 y5 z1
26  x1 y1 z2
27  x2 y1 z2
28  x3 y1 z2
29  x4 y1 z2
30  x5 y1 z2
31  x1 y2 z2
32  x2 y2 z2
33  x3 y2 z2
34  x4 y2 z2
35  x5 y2 z2
36  x1 y3 z2
37  x2 y3 z2
38  x3 y3 z2
39  x4 y3 z2
40  x5 y3 z2
41  x1 y4 z2
42  x2 y4 z2
43  x3 y4 z2
44  x4 y4 z2
45  x5 y4 z2
46  x1 y5 z2
47  x2 y5 z2
48  x3 y5 z2
49  x4 y5 z2
50  x5 y5 z2
51  x1 y1 z3
52  x2 y1 z3
53  x3 y1 z3
54  x4 y1 z3
55  x5 y1 z3
56  x1 y2 z3
57  x2 y2 z3
58  x3 y2 z3
59  x4 y2 z3
60  x5 y2 z3
61  x1 y3 z3
62  x2 y3 z3
63  x3 y3 z3
64  x4 y3 z3
65  x5 y3 z3
66  x1 y4 z3
67  x2 y4 z3
68  x3 y4 z3
69  x4 y4 z3
70  x5 y4 z3
71  x1 y5 z3
72  x2 y5 z3
73  x3 y5 z3
74  x4 y5 z3
75  x5 y5 z3
76  x1 y1 z4
77  x2 y1 z4
78  x3 y1 z4
79  x4 y1 z4
80  x5 y1 z4
81  x1 y2 z4
82  x2 y2 z4
83  x3 y2 z4
84  x4 y2 z4
85  x5 y2 z4
86  x1 y3 z4
87  x2 y3 z4
88  x3 y3 z4
89  x4 y3 z4
90  x5 y3 z4
91  x1 y4 z4
92  x2 y4 z4
93  x3 y4 z4
94  x4 y4 z4
95  x5 y4 z4
96  x1 y5 z4
97  x2 y5 z4
98  x3 y5 z4
99  x4 y5 z4
100 x5 y5 z4
101 x1 y1 z5
102 x2 y1 z5
103 x3 y1 z5
104 x4 y1 z5
105 x5 y1 z5
106 x1 y2 z5
107 x2 y2 z5
108 x3 y2 z5
109 x4 y2 z5
110 x5 y2 z5
111 x1 y3 z5
112 x2 y3 z5
113 x3 y3 z5
114 x4 y3 z5
115 x5 y3 z5
116 x1 y4 z5
117 x2 y4 z5
118 x3 y4 z5
119 x4 y4 z5
120 x5 y4 z5
121 x1 y5 z5
122 x2 y5 z5
123 x3 y5 z5
124 x4 y5 z5
125 x5 y5 z5
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `crossing`

```
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
invoke(crossing, df)
```